# Reduce the effect of half wave rectifier on transformer

Tags: transformer, dc, rectifier, waveform, power-factor-correction

I have an electromagnetic feeder drive which is supplied from a transformer.

When I see the catalogue of the drive I noticed it using just the positive pulse of the AC source (half wave rectifier.)
This causes a DC component which heats the transformer up. To be sure I used a oscilloscope to see the current wave:

[image: current wave]

One solution would be to add a second load using the negative wave like this:

[image: negative half wave rectifier]

1. Is there any other solution?
2. Will this make the transformer smaller than the load (the load is 600 watt, the transformer is 1 KVA, the second load may be 400 to 600 watt.)

Comment: Are you sure that it's the DC component that is causing your heat problem?  While that does add to it generally the majority of transformer heat is due to core losses caused by the induced currents from the AC.

Comment: yes I am sure, I tried 3 different transformer with same problem on the load.

Comment: Why not use a FW rectifier to the load?

Comment: @Andyaka the half wave rectifier is probably used to limit power to the load. Its a cheap and simple solution. Its often done with heater elements.

Comment: @RaedSlekh "yes I am sure, I tried 3 different transformer with same problem on the load". Try loading the xformers with a 'normal' load and see if they get just as hot

Comment: @PrathikPrashanth - the OP should address this. My comment was for the OP.

Comment: Logical. It is "power electronics". The power factor for a full wave rectifier is 0.636. In case of simple rectifier, it is = 0.2865 (sorry). So a transformer must be sur-dimensionned by a factor 1/0.2865 ~= 3.3 ... the power delivered to load ... If the load = 600 W then the transformer must be for 1800 VA.

Comment: @antonio51 i tried 2.5 KVA transformer with same problem

Comment: Ok. More "difficult" then. Have you some infos about your feeder ? What are the scale on scope for current ?

Comment: Have you an idea about the "inductance" of your feeder  ?

Comment: I have seen a model such  "SAS electromagnetic vibrating feeders drive" model LE1 to LE4, it seems that there is a control unit with a "thyristor" drive. So power factor can be worst than I thought ... Perhaps 0.15 ??? I did not found a example schematic.